# How to avoid getting error "duplicate entry '1' for key primary" when inserting one table into another?

Tags: mysql, insert-into

```
INSERT INTO tableA (SELECT * FROM tableB);
```

creates an error

> "Duplicate entry '1' for key Primary".

tableA has field "Lid" which is primary, auto-increment and causing the error.

tableB has a set of records with identical fields to tableA. Field Lid is numbered 1-40.

I need ALL records from tableB to be appended to tableA every time a new user logs in to my system. Once copied to TableA, the records are updated with that users UserID. When tableB is appended to tableA, field tableA.Lid should autoincrement, not take the duplicate value from tableB.

The following works but I want to avoid specifying field names in code:

```
INSERT INTO tableA (field2, field3,...) SELECT field2, field3, ... FROM tableB
```

I skip field1 which is the "Lid" primary auto-increment field.

If I set tableB.Lid to null would this work?

I want to use `INSERT INTO tableA (SELECT * FROM tableB)` as this avoids specifying field names in code.

Comment: Yeah, well, what you want and what you can do are two different things. SQL set the rules decades ago. You have to do it the hard way. I think you have a solution here, even if it's less than ideal in your opinion. Being specific about columns might seem like a bad plan, but it's often a good idea in retrospect.

Comment: " I want to avoid specifying field names in code" ...actually this is usually considered a bad practice. Specifying the field names is a good thing. It a) increases the readability (and therefore maintainability) of your code, b) avoids ambiguity about which fields are being written to, c) avoids accidentally breaking the query when schema changes are made (e.g. columns added/removed, or the order changed), and d) gives you the flexibility to solve problems like the one you've having. You've already found the solution, now you need to use it.

Comment: P.S. It's unclear why you even have two tables with identical definitions? What is the purpose of that? It usually indicates a flawed, de-normalised data structure. You say "I need ALL records from tableB to be appended to tableA every time a new user logs in to my system. "...but why do you need that? What is the copied data supposed to represent? Are you sure you couldn't just set some extra property on the original table instead of duplicating everything?

Comment: "I want to avoid specifying field names in code".  You either follow the rule, or don't insert records into table.  Also it's a very bad habit to omit column names.  Since you're still learning, it's a good idea to learn good habits as well.

Comment: In response to ADyson, I have a set of master materials with pricing (tableB) that all users get a copy of when they log in for the first time. Each user can then amend their own set of materials (in tableA with their UserId) with pricing etc to suit them. I kick-start their work by providing a standard set of materials. Yes there will be other ways to do this.

Comment: I appreciate the responses. In tableB i changed field "Lid" to just be a regular INT field, not indexed, not primary, not auto-increment, default to Null. I am now able to "INSERT INTO tableA SELECT * FROM tableB" and all records in tableA are auto-incrementing correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In tableB i changed field "Lid" to just be a regular INT field, not indexed, not primary, not auto-increment, default to Null. I am now able to "INSERT INTO tableA SELECT * FROM tableB" and all records in tableA are auto-incrementing correctly. As mentioned I preferred not to use field names in code so wanted to keep solution "generic".